# Error "SolutionDir property not found in project" when installing SlowCheetah

Tags: nuget, slowcheetah

I wanted to try out SlowCheetah so I:

1. Created a test web project (ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application in Visual C#)
2. Enabled Package Restore by checking "Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build"
3. Installed SlowCheetah via Package Manager Console with `Install-Package SlowCheetah`.

Since I'd like this to work with a build server later on, I got a bit worried when this error message shows up:

```
SolutionDir property not found in project [TestWeb].
Have you enabled NuGet Package Restore? This is required for build server support.
You may need to enable it and to enable it and re-install this package
```

What does it mean and why can't it find `SolutionDir`?

Comment: If you enabled pig restore for that project you should not see this. Are you still seeing it?